# AI issue using Synaptic.js

Tags: javascript, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I try to make a simple game like arkanoid, but using SynapticJs (neural network library).

In the first step, I create a ship, and a ball. The ball bounce in the limits of canvas, and ship, only move for X axis, and stop in the limits. Now I don't created a blocks, for make it more easy for the moment. The only that I need is that the ship, hit the ball for don't lose the life.

I use a neural Perceptron network style, and a LSTM for other attempt. 
Use 3 inputs for neural network:

> - X position of ball
> - Y position of Ball
> - X position of ship

And 1 output:

> -If >0.5 move left, else, move right (20px)

Of any update of game (100 ms), I pass this info to network, and move the ship.

I use 12 entities (different networks). When the ship lose the ball, change to next network. When all 12 networks was losed, I get 2 that have more points (1 point for one hit ball-ship), and mix his "neurons", and make a little mutation to his bias and weights, and create 10 more networks. Get this networks and 2 winners, and play the game again.

But I can't make he learn... The maximum was 7 hits once a time, but for each loop, he repeatly the same move.

Now I use a LSTM(3,12,12,1), and don't hit more than 2 times in 700 entities (58 generations)

¿What is the problem?

PD: I use the code of this git for generate the new generations:

```
https://github.com/ivanseidel/IAMDinosaur
```

The code is in learner.js if you want to see it

Comment: Can you show some of your code?

Comment: it seem like you may need to set up a genetical algorithm for this. I have created a genetic algorithm version of synaptic.js for you to check out here https://github.com/wagenaartje/gynaptic